# Get object on Entity Framework Core interceptor before insert command

Tags: orm, entity-framework-core

For some reason i want to get object before it was inserted on `Ef Core Intreceptor` , for ex when i want

```
  var newOrder = new Order { CustomerID = 3, EmployeeID = 4, OrderDate = DateTime.Now };
        _myContext.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        _myContext.SaveChanges();
```

i try to get `newOrder` on `ReaderExecuting` method of `Interceptor` so i override this method :

```
   public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }
```

this method is called, so how can i get `newOrder` on above method?

I know in `NHibernate` we can doing this like this:

```
 public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent @event)
    {

        //some other codes
    }
```

i can get the the object by `@event.Entity`, but in `Ef Core 3` is there any way to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but just in case someone come here in search for an answer to this.

Microsoft added a bunch of new, actually useful interceptors to EF core 7, which runs on .NET 6 despite its name btw.

I think the interceptors before EF core 7 were a lot less useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.iinterceptor?view=efcore-7.0

Just expand the 'Derived' section and it will show you a list of interceptors available.

If you want to edit an entity before it gets saved in the DB you can use the `SaveChangesInterceptor`. Just create a class that inherits from it and override the `SavingChanges` method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.savechangesinterceptor?view=efcore-7.0